# Finding the first duplicate element in an ordered list

Tags: python, pseudocode

I'm new to coding and hit a wall as to what to do with my pseudo code.
I am defining a first duplicate function that for a = [1 2 2 3 4 4] it returns 2,

```
def firstDuplicate(a):
# put first element into new list (blist)
# check second element to blist
# if same, return element and end
# else, try next blist element 
# if no next element, add to end of blist
# do the same with third element (counter) and so on until end of list

alist = list(a)
blist = list(a[1])
bleh = 1
comp = 2

if list(a[comp]) == blist[bleh]:
    return list(a[comp]) # and end
if else bleh = bleh+1 # and repeat til last blist element
# to stop? 

else blist = blist+list(a[2]) # append outside of blist?
```

This is what I've done so far. Any suggestions what I do next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return the first number that appears a second time while you're iterating over the list. To achieve this I would use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and check if the current item is already in the set, if yes return it, otherwise add the item to the set. (You could do that with a list, too, but less efficiently.)

```
def firstDuplicate(a):
    set_ = set()
    for item in a:
        if item in set_:
            return item
        set_.add(item)
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you would be interested in a single line code by list comprehension

```
a = [10,34,3,5,6,7,6,1,2]

print [n for i , n in enumerate(a) if n in a[i+1:] and n not in a[:i]][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,]

def find_it(look_here):
    have_seen = set()
    for item in look_here:
        if item in have_seen:
            return item
        have_seen.add(item)

find_it(a)
2
```